# Gpg hangs when listing keys (docker install)

Tags: dockerfile, gnupg, alpine-linux

I try to setup a docker image to tar and encrypt files.

My problem is when I try to do it with a Dockerfile, when I `gpg --list-keys`, shell hangs and nothing happens.

There is no error message. I see nothing in logs.

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:3
COPY public.asc /
RUN apk add --no-cache gnupg openssh && ssh-keygen -A && mkdir /root/.ssh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 22/tcp
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN gpg --import /public.asc
```

If I delete the `RUN gpg --import /public.asc` and run it directly into a shell attached to the container and then `gpg --list-keys`, it's working fine and returning the key.

Maybe I'm missing something on how Docker is building the image ?

Answer (score 6):

Removing the lock file did the trick.

Snippet from my Dockerfile

Key Import

```
RUN gpg --batch --import path_to_key.pub
```

Removing the lock file

```
RUN rm -f /home/my_user/.gnupg/public-keys.d/pubring.db.lock
```

After each key import, you might have to remove the lock file.

Comment: this fixed gpg on my Mac, when it hung for everything after the computer crashed.